# Why can't I use a generic type constraint in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, types, extends, generic-type-argument

Why can't I use a generic type constraint in Scala?
This is my code

```
abstract class Adder[T]{
    def +(a: Matrix[T], that: Matrix[T]): Matrix[T]
    def *(a: Matrix[T], that: Matrix[T]): Matrix[T]
    def show(a: Matrix[T]): Unit 
}

object Adder{

    implicit object TDouble extends Adder[T <: Double] {
        override def +(a: Matrix[T], that: Matrix[T]): Matrix[T] = {
            if (that.M != a.M || that.N != a.N) throw new RuntimeException("Illegal matrix dimensions.");
            var C = Array.ofDim[T](a.M,a.N);
            for (i <- 0  to a.M - 1)
                for (j <- 0  to a.N - 1){
                    C(i)(j) = a.matrix(i)(j) + that.matrix(i)(j);
                }
            new Matrix(C)
        }       
    }
}
```

this is error

```
scala:11: error: ']' expected but ':' found.
    implicit object TDouble extends Adder[T: <: Double] {
```

I want all numerical types to be processed in this object

Comment: The posted code is incomplete and contains many errors. If you "want all numerical types to be processed" then `[T <: Double]` won't do it. (In fact, that won't do anything.) You'll need to use the `Numeric` type class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question ``Why can't I use a generic type constraint in Scala?`` is too broad, and then seems to lead up to a problem statement to be solved by someone else than you... Try to ask a specific question. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in particular at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Finally, Stack Overflow isn't supposed to be a replacement for great online tutorials and books (on Scala).

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with "can't use a generic type constraint". It is simply a trivial typo.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is close to what you want?

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

//this is just a guess at what your Matrix might look like
class Matrix[A](val matrix :Array[Array[A]]) {
  val M:Int = matrix.length
  val N:Int = matrix.head.length
}

implicit class MatrixOps[T:Numeric:ClassTag](a :Matrix[T]) {
  val nOps = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
  import nOps._
  def +(that :Matrix[T]) :Matrix[T] = {
    if (that.M != a.M || that.N != a.N)
      throw new RuntimeException("Illegal matrix dimensions.")
    val c = Array.ofDim[T](a.M, a.N)
    for (i <- 0 until a.M)
      for (j <- 0 until a.N)
        c(i)(j) = a.matrix(i)(j) + that.matrix(i)(j)
    new Matrix(c)
  }
}
```

With this you should be able to add any two Matrix instances as long as the dimensions and numeric types (`Int`,`Float`,etc.) match.